# Using T in an array of functions in C#

Tags: c#

is there any way of doing this:

```
    static Func<T>[] x = new Func<T>[4];
```

successfully in C#?

This code is giving me a "Type T could not be found" error.

What I'm trying to do is to call one of a series of methods that will be used in this context:

```
    y = SerializationHelper<T>.Serialize(x[i]());
```

My alternative is to use a switch/case, but I'd prefer a table.

Comment: It would have to be in a generic class.

Comment: Are you working with a generic class? If not, `T` would be undefined.

Comment: Please provide more context. The type variable `T` should be declared somewhere; perhaps you moved the implementation to the wrong scope?

Comment: Generic type parameters are declared on the class or function level.

Comment: I suppose you want to define an array of delegates where every delegate may have its own type for the argument. The problem is, that all those delegates represent completely different types. There´s nothing common between `Func<int>` and `Func<MyType>`, which is why you can´t (effectivly) put them into a single collection (unless you omit the constraint completely and work with the ungeneric `Delegate`)

Comment: Where does the type of the `T` for your SerializationHelper come from? Use the same when declaring your func array.

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't *declared* the generic parameter `T`.

Your code would have to be *inside* a generic **class...**

```
class Class<T> // <-- Generic parameter declared at class level
{
    static Func<T>[] x = new Func<T>[4];
}
```

or **method..**

```
static void Method<T>() // <-- Generic parameter declared at method level
{
    Func<T>[] x = new Func<T>[4];
}
```

..that has a generic parameter `T` declared.

You **cannot** declare a generic variable, field or property. This is **NOT** possible in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
class SerializationHelper
{
   public void Serialize<W,T>(W data,Func<int,T> x) where W : IEnumerable
   {
        //do something with data using Func
        foreach(int i in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x(i));
        }
   }
}

Func<int,int> x = (i) => {return i*i; };  // Takes one integer as input and returns square of it

new SerializationHelper().Serialize<int[],int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, x);
```

Method Serialize has two open types W (for data) and T (for delegate) with IEnumerable constraint on W. Instead of using Func you can introduce an additional open type Z in Serialize method and use Func instead. After that you can call serialize method by specifying closed types and passing appropriate parameters of those type as shown in the example. The example calculates square of all the numbers using delegate passed as second argument of Serialize method.